# Pasting into SSH on remote server causes weird characters aka bracketed paste

Tags: server, ssh, text, putty

When I connect to any of my remote Ubuntu servers, most if not all will print extra characters at the front and back of the pasted text.

I'm using putty 0.70 for Windows 10 Pro 64 bit.

> 0~/home/kreezxil/work/cobbleblock/./mods/clumps-3.1.1.jar1~

The 0~ and 1~ are the extra characters I'd like to make go away.

My locale output on the Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS server is:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

cat /etc/default/locale

```
#  File generated by update-locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE="en_US:"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

#### Amended February 18 2019

I've recently learned this called **bracketed paste** and when you search google for that term, you find many articles in many situations related to the issue. Nearly all of them describe my problem to a tee but their solutions don't fit me as the problem is occurring while grabbing text from windows 10 and pasting in ssh session on my Linux servers.

#### Later that Day

On a whim I decided to completely uninstall putty and perform a registry clean up and junk file removal afterwards thus ensuring it and all of it's various settings are removed from my system.

Learned that Windows 10 has it's own SSH now powered by OpenSSH. Tried it and didn't get the **bracketed pasting**. But didn't like that it didn't provide me enough automation, for instance it lacks -pw (password) option.

Then I reinstalled putty, this time choosing the 32 bit version, I've always used the 64 bit, but this time I went with 32 bit. Success, no more **bracketed pasting**.

I recognize this like the good comments below is a solution but not **THE SOLUTION**. I'm not entirely willing to accept the first answer below although it is good as it didn't apply to my situation and even when I asked the question I had not known exactly how to phrase the question. It is my hope that my experience and what I found out will help someone later to resolve a similar issue.

#### Even more time has passed, now it's October 6 2019

I have since reinstalled my operating system and gotten the latest version of putty which was 0.73 and yes I got the 64 bit and yes it does bracketed. Then I rediscovered my own question here and followed all the suggestion but this time even 32 bit 0.73 does bracketed which leads me to believe that someone on the putty dev team really likes bracketed.

In the comments you see I said I would try 0.70 32bit. **That is a good idea** because it does not have the bracketed issue.

Comment: Check the `$TERM` value. Check the setup of your `$PS1` (prompt) variable in your `~/.bashrc`, documented in `man bash`, the "Prompting" section.

Comment: @waltinator I found the type of problem described on the internet as "bracketed paste" https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=174595 and https://midnight-commander.org/ticket/3207 easily describe the problem I am trying to convey. I think the issue is Windows 10 related as it doesn't happen when I am on the Linux side of my computer.

Comment: Followup, now on putty 0.73 32bit, the bracketed paste has been now introduced to the 32bit. Going to uninstall and drop back to 0.70 to see if it stays away. It would seem someone in the putty dev team is setting bracketed paste mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A friend of mine was experiencing this same issue.

Turns out he was also using the 64 bit version of Putty 0.70, based on my experience as outlined in the opening statement I told him that it sounded like it was putty at fault here. I had him uninstall it and install the 32 bit version of Putty 0.70. The bracketed pasting immediately stopped.

There is no section in the putty settings for disabling this behavior. Next step is to report it to the Putty development branch for 64 bit.

In short if you are going from windows to shell in putty and you are receiving bracketed paste characters check to see if you are using 64 bit Putty.You can check this by opening putty and clicking on the "about" button.

[image: where to find the version]